# A 3D scene within a 3D scene

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

Consider a camera (on a plane) viewing a 3D model of terrain. Imagine now that it takes a photograph of what it sees. I would like to view the terrain from a different camera (even move that camera around) and I would like to see the picture taken by the plane projected on the terrain.

My current approach has been as follows:

- Create a 3D scene representing the plane view.
- Create a 3D scene representing the observer view.
- Inside the latter scene there is a model of the terrain upon which I project the whole 3D scene from the plane.

It doesn't work as expected - I won't go into the details quite yet, but can anyone say whether they think this would be the right approach?

Maybe one scene is sufficient with some matrix magic?

Answer (score 2):

I think the general way of doing something like this rendering the plane view to a texture, then overlaying that texture on the terrain in the observer view.

Unless of course that's what you're already doing.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am doing, but I have a number of problems.
I would like the terrain itself to be rendered in the observer's view - only the photo taken by the plane should be overlaid above it.
So I put the photo in an empty canvas and I see only the photo showing through (I have a border around the canvas for debugging so this shows on the terrain too)
First problem is that the canvas' border does not cover the entire terrain area - even though both visuals have the same 2D size and the cameras in both viewports are positioned identically.
How can I ensure that the surfaces map exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you further there. I don't know enough about WPF or your specific project.